# How to calculate if two polygon intersects or not?

Tags: geometry

Lets say I have a collection of points (**First polygon**) (x<sub>1<sub>1</sub></sub>,y<sub>1<sub>1</sub></sub>),(x<sub>1<sub>2</sub></sub>,y<sub>1<sub>2</sub></sub>),(x<sub>1<sub>3</sub></sub>,y<sub>1<sub>3</sub></sub>),...,(x<sub>1<sub>n</sub></sub>,y<sub>1<sub>n</sub></sub>)

And another collection of points (**Second polygon**) (x<sub>2<sub>1</sub></sub>,y<sub>2<sub>1</sub></sub>),(x<sub>2<sub>2</sub></sub>,y<sub>2<sub>2</sub></sub>),(x<sub>2<sub>3</sub></sub>,y<sub>2<sub>3</sub></sub>),...,(x<sub>2<sub>m</sub></sub>,y<sub>2<sub>m</sub></sub>)

How to calculate if they intersect or not ?

Comment: Please try a web search for "polygon intersection algorithm". You will find lots of references, some on this site.

Comment: There are good algorithms if one or both polygons are convex.